# Where is the default QGIS Point layer style .qml file installed in Win 32?

Tags: qgis, qml

Where is the default QGIS Point layer style .qml file installed in a Windows 32 bit installation? I have done a search on *.qml and can only find four python plugins styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a symbology file. The default would be

```
~/.qgis/symbology-ng-style.xml
```

QMLs are layer style files. Reusable symbol libraries are stored in XMLs which can be imported and exported using Style Manager.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I seem to have "lost" the default point style. When I make a new point layer and then add points to it there is no symbol displayed though I can display an attribute label! at the position of the point.  Im trying to "get back" the default point symbol. I have worked round it by opening a point layer that does have a symbol and saving that as my own default style.